# Patching 2.3.6 via composer

Tags: magento2, patches, magento2.3.6

For patching 2.3.6 via composer the [docs state](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/patching/composer.html)

> If a patch affects multiple modules, you must create multiple patch
> files targeting multiple modules.

Therefore is there a correct set of patch files for [MC-38033](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051235772)?
The reason is MC-38033 span across multiple modules

Answer (score 0):

If you open one of the patch files (`git` or `composer`) from [Magento Commerce v2.3.6/2.4.1 CAPTCHA in checkout not working / MC-38033](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051235772) you can see there are multiple modules which the patch applies to:

- app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/
- app/code/Magento/Multishipping/
- app/code/Magento/Checkout/

One patch file can apply to multiple modules.